# Unable to get the element from shadow dom using Cypress

Tags: input, css-selectors, cypress, shadow-dom

I have been trying to fill a login page using Cypress and the fields are listed under a shadow DOM. I can get to the shadow (I believe) but finding the #email (CSS) does not happen and times out. Can someone help me and tell what am I missing or doing wrong? BTW tried the same with Playwright as well but no success (App is CANVAS/Flutter and not very friendly exposing locators and interaction with tools)
Looks like I am not getting the right element [email/password]. It gives assertion error and never finds #email/#current-password

```js
 it('Edison Launchpad ', function(){
        cy.visit('https://staging.edisoninteractive.tv');
       // cy.get('body > :nth-child(17)').type('asadW@abc.com')
       cy.get('flt-glass-pane')
       .shadow
       cy.get('#email')
       cy.type('asadW@abc.com')
       cy.get('#current-password')
       cy.type('jdkjdkjdkdjdkjdkjdkjdkjd')
       .should('contain.text', 'email');
 })
```

Comment: The canvas inside `flt-glass-pane` is interfering with the normal testing commands. Manually doing a rightclick adds or exposes a `<form>` to the DOM (which has the inputs you want to type into) at which point your test can proceed, but I can't get Cypress to automate that first step.

Comment: It goes up to the hosting 'flt-glass-pane' and after that does not see anything and times out on the element. I wasn't sure if I placed the correct root.

Comment: There is an example Cypress test here [canvas-kit/cypress/integration/FormField.spec.ts](https://github.com/Workday/canvas-kit/blob/master/cypress/integration/FormField.spec.ts) that I presume is working, but I cannot decipher the way it works (unfortunately is not written for clarity).

Comment: There are two issues: 1. It is Canvas/Flutter based. 2. The input fields under the forms are residing within a Shadow DOM. I am not sure in the example, if the example is handling the shadow objects. Will go through though thanks.

Comment: The shadow dom is created by the canvas-kit elements. Since that is the repository for canvas-kit and they advocate using Cypress, it must be possible. The problem is they spend a lot of time explaining why Cypress is good in general but give no documentation explaining how to do the tests.