# How to execute document.querySelector with Playwright or Cypress

Tags: javascript, css, cypress, shadow-dom, playwright

I am using an application which is using Shadow dom and Iam unable to pierce the Shadow and keep the state as neither Cypress nor Playwright are able to identify the elements and fill the input fields. Last option is to use query selector to see if it allows me to login to the app. Can someone tell me how should I execute the document.querySelector so I can fill the forms?

I have tried to call the CSS (#email/#current-password) from Playwright. It only finds the first field at times and not consistent.

For Cypress- I tried to get to the Shadow element but it times out and says #email never found.

Playwright:

```
     await page.keyboard.press("Tab") 
     ///await page.locator('input#email:visible').fill('pwdstr');
     await page.fill("#email", "asad.test@tests.com")
     await page.keyboard.press("Tab") // need to tab since unable to focus/click the field
     await page.locator('input#current-password:visible').fill('pwdstr');
     await page.locator('#current-password >> nth=0').type('kkkkkkkkkk');

Cypress: 
   

 cy.visit('https://staging.edisoninteractive.tv');
   // cy.get('body > :nth-child(17)').type('asadW@abc.com')
   cy.get('flt-glass-pane')
   .shadow()
   .find("#email")
   cy.type('asadW@abc.com')
   cy.get('#current-password')
   cy.type('jdkjdkjdkdjdkjdkjdkjdkjd')
   .should('contain.text', 'email');

    document.querySelector("body > flt-glass-pane:nth-child(17)").shadowRoot.querySelector("#email").value"asad.test@test.com"
    
    document.querySelector("body > flt-glass-pane:nth-child(17)").shadowRoot.querySelector("#current-password").value"abcdddddd"
    
    document.querySelector("body > flt-glass-pane:nth-child(17)").shadowRoot.querySelector("flt-semantics-placeholder").click()

      [![enter image description here][1]][1]
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDnXw.png
```

Comment: Can I use something like below? 
    let str1="body> flt-glass-pane:nth-child(17)"
    console.log(str1)
    page.fill(str1.shadowRoot.querySelector("#email"),'emailstr')

Comment: Did you mean to [edit] your post? Wasn't this question asked yesterday a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73978296/unable-to-get-the-element-from-shadow-dom-using-cypress) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980796/unable-to-fill-edit-fields-from-shadow-dom-using-playwright)? https://staging.edisoninteractive.tv doesn't load for me so I can't reproduce the issue.